# mongo Bulk Operations speed in 3.6 version and before version

Tags: mongodb

I Find this article.
Write Command Batch Limit Size
100,000 writes are allowed in a single batch operation, defined by a single request to the server.

Changed in version 3.6: The limit raises from 1,000 to 100,000 writes. This limit also applies to legacy OP_INSERT messages.

The Bulk() operations in the mongo shell and comparable methods in the drivers do not have this limit.

so when many data , example, 1000000 record. 3.6 version vs before.
in 3.6 before version,Will it be much less efficient?

Answer (score 0):

While the server has raised its limit from 1,000 to 100,000 documents/write, your application is most likely uses a MongoDB driver and drivers have their own limit which, nominally, happens to be 1,000 documents/write (see https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/driver-bulk-update.rst under "request size limits"). The driver will split writes that exceed this limit into multiple commands.

Note that the reason given for splitting at 1,000 documents is that the server is able to return an error message for each document should the insert fail. A driver may provide an option to use the server-provided document count limit (100,000) or a custom limit.

You can patch a driver locally to raise the limit from 1,000 to 100,000 if you have a huge number of small documents you are inserting. Alternatively you can issue the write commands yourself (e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/insert/) and provide up to 100,000 documents that way.